# How do I offset for loop in a django template by one

Tags: python, django

I want to show my newest post in my header and have the other posts in the for loop to be offset by one, so there's not the same post in my header and another where all my other posts are.

in my views.py I have

```
 latest = Post.objects.latest('id')

 context = {
    ......
    "latest": latest
  }
```

in my list.html

```
 <div class="jumbotron col-sm-12">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <p>{{latest}}</p>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
                <img src='{{ latest.image.url }}' class="img-responsive"/>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4 pull-right" style="background-color: #212121; height: 300px">


            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and

```
 {% for q in object_list %}
    {{ q.title }}
 {% endfor %}
```

how do I offset my for loop by 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are getting your `object_list` from the context, I would suggest that you remove the first object there only:

```
object_list[1:]
```

but, if you do want to do it in the template, you can use the builtin [`slice`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#slice) filter:

```
{% for q in object_list|slice:"1:" %}
    {{ q.title }}
 {% endfor %}
```

It uses the same syntax as python list for slicing.

> Uses the same syntax as Python’s list slicing. See http://www.diveintopython3.net/native-datatypes.html#slicinglists for an introduction.

---

An alternative way could be to exclude the `latest` object from the `object_list`

```
object_list = object_list.exclude(id=latest.id)
```

and, then you don't need to slice the list.

Comment: thanks for all of your approaches I'll use the last one thanks

Comment: Glad to be of help. Please accept the answer if it works.